# ImmutableMap.Builder from a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, guava, builder, immutable-collections

I have a `HashMap<K,V>` of defaults values per keys.

I want to convert it to an `ImmutableMap.Builder` As I have another `ImmutableMap` which I want to merge and override into the original HashMap.  I want to override some of the default pairs and eventually build a `ImmutableMap`.

How can I convert the `HashMap` to `ImmutableMap.Builder`?

I haven't seen `ImmutableMap.Builder` [constructor](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.Builder.html) that gets a `HashMap`.

Comment: Why can't you just call `put()` to add the pairs you want to override, then wrap in `Collections.unmodifiableMap()`?

Comment: If you mean the Guava immutable map, then you need to use `ImmutableMap.of()` instead of `ImmutableMap.builder()`.

Comment: @MichaelBerry -- I'm guessing it's because, counter-intuitively, Unmodifiable != Immutable. Read this: https://www.baeldung.com/java-immutable-maps

Comment: Also, be careful with this -- using `of()` can be computationally expensive because the original map is copied, not referenced -- the immutable map takes a private copy of your data to protect it against changes via a different reference to it.

Comment: https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.Builder.html#putAll(java.util.Map)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use `putAll` or am I missing something here? You cannot modify existing keys while building, but you can add more:

```
    Map<String, String> srcMap = Map.of("A", "a", "B", "b", "C", "c");

    ImmutableMap<String, String> map = ImmutableMap.<String, String> builder()
            .putAll(srcMap)
            .put("D", "d")
            .build();

    map.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.printf ("[%s:%s]", k, v));
```

You could modify the `srcMap` itself before you invoke `putAll` if you want to override the existing values.

Also, if you have a HashMap that is ready to be converted to an ImmutableMap, you can skip the builder part and just use `copyOf`:

```
ImmutableMap<String, String> finalMap = ImmutableMap.copyOf(srcMap);
```